# How to determine a server WebSocket url when the address is unknown at build time?

Tags: angular, websocket, server

Although I'm relatively new to web sockets, my development environment's Angular-7 client and node/express development server are communicating using WebSockets quite successfully.

The problem is that, in deployment, the actual server will be running on a portable instrument which itself can reside at **any** Manual IP address on **any** customer's network.

There are numerous examples of using Angular with WebSockets. All of them use known IP addresses. The techniques I'm folowing are quite simple. The basic WebSocket creation code is shown below:

**websocket.service.ts**

```
 constructor() {
    this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject(environment.wsUrl);
    this.subscription$ = this.socket$
      .subscribe(
      (message) => this.processWebSocketMessage(message),
      (err) => console.error(err),
      () => console.warn('Connection closed')
    );
  }
```

**environment.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  wsUrl: 'ws://localhost:8999'
};
```

My problem is that I have found no examples of what the *wsUrl* property value should be for a production build (*environment.prod.ts*) for a server whose IP address is unknown at build time.

I strongly suspect I'm missing something very simple here. Should I be determining the server IP address dynamically? All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Environment properties are for static data. You need to be able to configure the URL at runtime. There are many ways to do this. What's wrong with reading a JSON file from the server?

Comment: Yes @cgTag, I've seen this technique discussed. It is a possibility as I have access to the server code to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Following deeper research and testing against multiple browsers. I have settled on the following solution. The browser already "knows" the address of the server. The only additional part is to supply the correct port based on the current environment.

**websocket.service.ts**

```js
   this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject(
     'ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':' + environment.wsPort
   );
```

**environment.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  wsPort: 8999
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  wsPort: 8080
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to have wsUrl in environment.ts. You can get the url through a service and then create your websocket socket.

**websocket.service.ts**

```
constructor(private servUrl:UrlService) {

servUrl.getUrlDinamicaly().subscribe(res => {

    this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject(res.wsUrl);

    this.subscription$ = this.socket$.subscribe(
      (message) => this.processWebSocketMessage(message),
      (err) => console.error(err),
      () => console.warn('Connection closed')
    );
  }
 );
}
```

**url-service.service.ts**

```
  getUrlDinamicaly(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.serverUrl + '/get_url_server');
  }
```

With **getUrlDinamicaly** you will get the current url of the  websocket server. The service server can not change its url.

Comment: I understand Yordano (Note that I believe there's a cut and paste error. Should _res.wsUrl_ be replaced with the call to _getUrlDynamically()_?)